# I need to get maven folder while creating project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have downloaded maven 3.x successfully but when I am opening eclipse ide  File > New > Project and need to select maven project then  I am not able to view the maven folder itself .I dont know whether I need m2e plugin or what as I am new to this .Please  guide me on this.

Comment: Maven installation download is primarily used for command line maven execution. And you can configure eclipse to use the installation download. However for eclipse you need to have m2e plugin installed for eclipse to support maven. You can verify if maven plugin is installed after going to prefrence->mavenand lower Yes you need to install m2e plugin and

Comment: Thanks                                        Another thing is that I was unable to download m 2 e  plugin . so can you please let me know a valid source of the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open *Help - Eclipse Marketplace* in Eclipse and then enter **m2e** or **maven plugin**. It depends on your eclipse version, what to install.

But there are also a lot of eclipse bundles, which already include the maven plugin like the Java EE version.